# Using the TYPE keyword in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I'm trying to understand the definition of the keyword `TYPE` in pascal. I understand that `typedef` in C just gives a new name to the type (alasing). But as I understand `TYPE` in Pascal does not work that way. It will create a new unique type.

I was trying to search and create a simple example which shows the mechanism of `TYPE`. I tried to create an example which creates some types and a function. After that, it pass each time one of the types to that function. It should fail because the function should get only one type, which proves that those types are not just aliasing. Due to my lack of knowledge of Pascal syntax, I failed each time.

Could you share a simple short program which proves the power of `TYPE`?

**EDIT**:

I have created the following example:

```
program Check;
TYPE
    Meters = Real; Seconds = Real;

VAR
    m: Meters; s: Seconds;

Procedure PRINT_SEC(s: Seconds);
    Begin
        WriteLn(s, ' sec');
    end;

Begin
    PRINT_SEC(s);
    PRINT_SEC(m);
end.
```

Output:

```
0.0000000000000000E+000 sec
0.0000000000000000E+000 sec
```

But why it does not fail? I passed `m` which has type `Meters` no? Also, How can I initialize those variables?

Comment: @MartynA I'm learning the concepts of PLs. I just trying to understand the concept of `TYPE` and why it is not `alasing`.

Comment: @MartynA Please checkout my example.

Comment: Beware that type system in pascal is much more evoluted than C. By chance you triggered a handy and simple "aliasing", but try to define a true different type, like `(Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs)` (it is an enumeration).

Answer (score 4):

First a minor point, in Pascal, the keyword TYPE does not create types. The keyword TYPE must occur before type definitions, but it is the type definitions which MAY create types. Not all type definitions create types.

The Pascal Standard says the following:

```
A type-definition shall introduce an identifier to denote a type.
```

which means a type definition introduces (i.e. creates or redefines) an identifier which denotes (i.e. is an alias for) a type.

The Pascal Standard defines a type definition as:

```
type-definition = identifier '=' type-denoter

type-denoter = type-identifier | new-type

new-type = new-ordinal-type | new-structured-type | new-pointer-type
```

Which means that a type definition is a identifier, followed by the equal side, followed by a type denoter. A type denoter is either a type identifier or a new type.

So a type identifier introduces an identifier that denotes (i.e. is an alias for) either another type identifier or a new-type. A type is created only in the case where the type denoter is a new type.

So in your example:

```
TYPE
    Meters = Real; Seconds = Real;
```

The type denoter in both type definitions is the type identifier Real, so Meters and Seconds are both aliases for Real.

Yes, in Pascal, **Real** is not a Type, it is a built-in type identifier for the real type.

The Pascal Standard says

> The required type identifier **real** shall denote the real-type.

So **real** is actually a type identifier and not a type. It is as if, there is an invisible type definition.

```
TYPE
    Real = real-type;
```

where real-type is the actual real type.

Answer (score 3):

Variables like `m` and `s` are defined by a type. In this case both types origins from a `real` type. That is called a `type alias`. They are compatible, both as a type and by assignment.

If you want a distinct type (in Freepascal and delphi), define:

```
type Seconds = type real;
```

That would have made the print procedure to only accept the `Seconds` type argument. Note that variables of `Seconds` and `Meters` declared as distinct types still are assignment compatible.

To initialize variables, just assign a value:

```
s := 42.0;
```

---

Note: most types are named starting with a `T`. Like `TSeconds`. Just to distinct them from variables. It is a common convention (in pascal).

Comment: ISTM that `type A = type B;` doesn't work in every Pascal. Only in, AFAIK, Delphi and FreePascal. The T prefix convention is also typical for Delphi/FreePascal, not for Pascal.

Comment: Later Turbo Pascal's at least had the T notation anywhere. Possibly it started due to Turbo Vision porting/codesharing with/from C.

Comment: @Marco: Turbo Pascal is not general Pascal. There are other Pascal implementations than Turbo Pascal, Delphi or FreePascal or compatibles (PascalScript etc.).

Comment: I know (FPC -Miso, remember?). Just wanted to make sure TP is included, since even now, its usage probably still dwarfs the others combined.